# How to Loop Through a Text File in a Makefile (GNU)?

Tags: loops, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a list of IDs inside a text file: pid.txt separated by space.
I want to run a python program for each of those ids. Which basically means I want to run the following commands:

```
python ./program.py id1
python ./program.py id2
python ./program.py id3
...
```

I am creating a makefile to do that.
But I am unable to write the appropriate code.
I have tried a lot of things like:

```
target:
       $(foreach var,$(pid.txt),python ./program.py $(var);)
```

But none of the approaches work.
Also, I want to parallelize this. Using -j.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother trying to use make constructions, just invoke a simple shell script.  eg:

```
target:
        for id in $$(cat pid.txt); do python ./program.py "$$id"; done
```

Depending on the desired behavior, you will probably want to do:

`...; do python ./program.py "$$id" || exit 1; done` to abort on a failure.

Comment: I also want to use -j for parallel processing. Will this for loop parallize?

Comment: You can make it run in parallel.  Slightly harder to check exit values if you just do `do python ./program.py "$$id" & done`.  You get more control if you use something like gnu parallel.

Answer (score 1):

With a canned recipe this is doable:

```
ID-INPUT := $(file < pid.txt)

define CREATE-PHONY-PYTHON =
PHONY: $1
$1:
        @echo calling Python with $1
        python ./program.py $1


endef

PHONY: all
all: $(ID-INPUT)

$(info $(foreach ID,$(ID-INPUT),$(call CREATE-PHONY-PYTHON,$(ID))))
$(eval $(foreach ID,$(ID-INPUT),$(call CREATE-PHONY-PYTHON,$(ID))))
```

The `$(info)` call is just there to check that the recipe generation is working like expected - delete it when in production. Parallelization should work as expected tho I couldn't check that.
You can take a look at [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) for more complex configuration processing inside make.

PS: the `$(file <)` function works only in GNUmake > 4.1 as I remember

Answer (score 0):

Use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).

```
# Use PIDS = $(shell cat pid.txt) on older versions of GNU make
PIDS = $(file < pid.txt)

# When a new pids are added, new files will be generated.
all: pid.txt $(PIDS)

# This way, you can build `make <pid>`
# I believe, the files should be re-generated when and only when `program.py` changes
$(PIDS): %: ./program.py
    python ./program.py "$*"
```